# excel formulas web application

Tags: excel, web-applications, formulas

We deal with business units who use excel sheets to import their data, and have various sheets  with parameters and formulas for their calculations. They have hit the data limitations of excel. In terms of designing a web based application for them, they will loose the calculation power of excel and their familiar environment. What would be the suggested design for such a web based application which can match the computation power of excel ?
We are exploring openrules etc. and mostly develop java based applications.
Can excel be used as a (web) client with access /mssql as a backend ?
Any other design/rules engines/framework suggestions would be helpful .

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the flexibility of Excel is pretty tough to beat for its generative power and flexibility.  I assume you don't want to repeat the 20+ years of development by the Microsoft Excel team to cover whatever obscure features your clients may expect.

One low cost option is try publishing the Excel file as a web page from within Excel.

Another option is to try Mathematica CDF.  Note, the CDF does require users to download the Mathematica browser plug in, and its one heck of a slug.  So some user bases can handle that, some can't. But anything you can do in Mathematica, and that's saying a lot, can be published as a CDF.  It's really fun to work with.

Comment: Thanks ! Have you used the web application interface for mathematica ? Where does the data reside ?   Is there a way to say have a template excel file with all the necessary formulas and lookup and use that probably through a java excel api, so that the business rules remain with the business people and I can then probably explore computational efficiency as a separate problem.

Answer (score 0):

The company I work for sells a development tool that could handle that problem.  It develops Java web apps, can create apps that mimic a spreadsheet interface, and lets you create and use all sorts of calculations.

It all depends on what types of calculations you need.  You could check out our site if you want ([www.mrc-productivity.com](http://www.mrc-productivity.com/index.html)), but it doesn't really get into much detail on calculations, as that's pretty advanced stuff.  To really know if it could handle everything you need, you would probably have to talk with one of our developers and explain exactly what you're looking for.  From what you described though, I'm fairly confident it can do what you need.